# Stock voice recorder, camera(video recording) and alarm not working in LG L90 dual D410

Tags: applications, lg

I have an LG L90 dual D410 running on Kitkat 4.2. Everything was working fine and I don't remember what caused these problems to occur. May be an update?

1. When I tried to record using the stock voice recorder, I get a message saying "Cannot start voice recording while other application is using audio", but record was success when tried using another app from the store.
2. The default camera's video recorder says "Unable to record video during call" but taking photo had no problem. And again video recording with another app was successful.
3. Stock alarm automatically goes to snooze mode without any sound but another alarm app works fine.

How do I solve these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems due to OK Google enable in all screen. To fix this, find the Google folder in apps, tap on Google settings, tap on Voice, then "Ok Google" Detection, uncheck the option From any screen, and make sure to check From Google Search app, if you still want to use Ok Google from Google app screen. Problems will be solved....

Comment: That solved it. But is this a bug? Should it be reported? This happens in LG only?

Comment: Most likely so. I did not know any report to Ok Google problem on other phone.